# Cloud Flow Designer - Screen - Lightning Component - Input Output Screen

Tags: lightning, visual-workflow

**PICTURES**

[Component Markup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZCkS.png)

[Design Attribute](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nyyYt.png)

[Screen Element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WjHrl.png)

[Entire Flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SYwuM.png)

I am building a flow which takes user input and then process further.

I am not able to get aura attribute of the Lightning Component in the flow.

I googgled and every answer shows the older UI of Screen component, where Input output and Field Settings tabs are available. However, I am not able to view them in Cloud flo designer.

Can anyone help me on this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: can you add code snippet and flow config screenshot?

Comment: Added Screenshots